# How to config Google Drive API on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-drive-api

I am a newbie developer on Ruby on Rails.

I have created a landing page with a form. This form is related to a Google Sheets document with the Google Drive API. 
I had no problem with the configuration locally. I have a config.json file generated and everything works fine.

The problem is in production with Heroku. I have configured Heroku with the config.json file as follow:

```
heroku config:add CONFIG_JSON='{ 
  "client_id": "xXxxxXXx",
  "client_secret": "xXxxxXXx",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "1/mUqALEa6lGi6ulkWdBTJSFeygauofgN-DhWaat8Crec"
}'
```

But it seems there is an additionnal step to do as I get an error as shown in the Heroku logs below:

```
2019-05-19T15:16:26.511306+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.511173 #4]  INFO -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iURPH06q8l6VrV9KOt9BLchtSB4S09TYKvf0SuQ8ydUnyBFZUwyRwe3R7+sWcpI9rXg1SyS0O1W65wDlDA+cgg==", "email"=>"prevostq@gmail.com", "commit"=>"Je m'inscris"}
2019-05-19T15:16:26.518244+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails: No such file or directory - gcloud
2019-05-19T15:16:26.559099+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-05-19T15:16:26.559103+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. Open this page:
2019-05-19T15:16:26.559106+00:00 app[web.1]: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=452925651630-egr1f18o96acjjvphpbbd1qlsevkho1d.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
2019-05-19T15:16:26.559108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-05-19T15:16:26.566902+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. Enter the authorization code shown in the page: I, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.566552 #4]  INFO -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms
2019-05-19T15:16:26.569268+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.569184 #4] FATAL -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21]   
2019-05-19T15:16:26.569784+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.569713 #4] FATAL -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21] NoMethodError (undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass):
2019-05-19T15:16:26.569877+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.569813 #4] FATAL -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21]   
2019-05-19T15:16:26.569981+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-05-19T15:16:26.569910 #4] FATAL -- : [6b76c96c-c2ac-406b-9f5e-b11db7e7fd21] app/controllers/landing_page_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

As anyone an idea on how to configure Heroku ?

Thank you in advance.
Quentin

Comment: Try saving `GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY` in config as we have provision to authenticate via private key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) ! If I understand well, I just have to replace the env var CONFIG_JSON by GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY ? Am I right ?
Thanks !

Comment: Exactly, I have tried this in same way in the past.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this in my opinion:

1. Use Private key in heroku config var: For communicating with sheet/drive api google provide us key as GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY which is used to authenticate  the request, hence can be used in env variables

   2.There is another method where we can point a json file in config eg

   heroku config:set GOOGLE_SETTING="$(cat settings.json)"

I haven't used this way but you can try it if it works for you.

While writing this answer one option came to my mind is you can use your config in json file

```
'{ 
  "client_id": "XXX",
  "client_secret": "XXX",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "XXX"
}'
```

Keeping all "XXX" in config rather than json file.

Pleae try all the possibilities and confirm if this resolves your issue.

Comment: I finally manage to make it working. The problem was finally not the upload of the variable to Heroku but the fact that my connection to Google Drive was through an OAuth client instead of a Service Account. 

Thank you for help anyway

Comment: Good to know that your issue has been fixed